# "received notices denying them rebates on those grounds."

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

**[SOURCE](https://books.google.com/books?id=iyw6ul1x_n8C&pg=PT28)**   (*Start with Why: How Great Leaders Inspire Everyone to Take Action*, Steven Sinek)

> - More than 4,000 Samsung customers lured by the cash back ***received*** notices denying ***them*** ***rebates*** on those grounds.

I have two questions based on this sentence.

1. does the word ***received*** mean here that: cash back which recieved notices, or what?
2. what is the meaning of ***them*** here, what it comes to my mine that the writer should exchange ***them*** with ***their*** rebates.

In brief, I want to know how this sentence works grammatically and meaningfully in context, especially the words I stressed on.

Comment: I could answer this question with what I presume is the intended meaning, but it's hard to be sure without a bit more context. Is it possible for you to add one or two sentences before "More than 4,000..."?

Comment: The rebates are _denied to_ the customers. Consult your English dictionary to learn what prepositions are taken by the verb _to deny_ . The examples there will show that the _to_ is frequently omitted, as in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The subject is **more than than 4,000  Samsung customers [who were] lured by the cash-back**

The finite verb is **received**.

The direct object is **notices**.

The modifying participial phrase (modifying **notices**) is **denying them rebates...** [i.e. them = the said customers...lured by...]

**them** is the indirect object of **denying** ; the direct object of **denying** is **rebates**.  In other words, denying rebates to those who had been lured.

P.S. Consider:

We went to the zoo, and visited the zebras. The zookeeper was attracting them with  carrots and **giving them inoculations** to protect them from diseases.

> More than a dozen zebras lured by the carrots received inoculations
>   protecting them from diseases.

Comment: Why doesn't commas exist to separate the context and make it meaningfully clear? Such as the writer could have put a comma between customers and received.

Comment: You need to be able to parse these constituents based on their functionality without the aid of typography.

Comment: @P. E. Dant imean in this way: More than 4,000 Samsung customers, lured by the cash back, received notices denying "their" rebates on those grounds.

Comment: @StevanSlewa That comma is between "customers" and "lured", not "Customers" and "received"! In any case, most English-speaking readers don't need commas to help them parse a simple (if ugly) sentence like this one. Writers use commas, often, where they would take a breath in speaking a given text. Such a comma indicates a pause: It's not part of a grammatical construct.

Comment: @StevanSlewa  I agree that commas would help, but this is not a particularly complicated sentence for native speakers.  I'm sure it will get easier the more you get familiar with English.

Comment: Since commas also change the restrictiveness of such clauses, they should be added or removed only delicately.